# Add JARs to NetBeans project (answer doesn't seem to work)

Tags: netbeans, jar

I'm trying to add JARs to a NetBeans project.

I've right-clicked on Libraries then selected Add JAR/Folder and selected the JARs, but the imports aren't recognised.

I know the imports are in those JARs because it works in Eclipse.

For example, the import statement

```
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
```

is underlined in red and has this error message:

```
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ChartFactory
  location: package org.jfree.chart
----
(Alt-Enter shows hints)
```

EDIT:

I've been using NetBeans 7.3.1 and JDK 7 u 25 (64-bit).

A zip file containing the project I get the above error with is (hopefully) available here: https://app.promobucket.com/the-church/spine-panel/a-sample-collection-1/splinepanel

The code is here:

```
package splinepanel;

import java.awt.*;       // Using AWT containers and components
import javax.swing.*;    // Using Swing components and containers
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;

/**
 *
 * @author User
 */
public class SplinePanel{

    public JPanel createContentPane(){

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("MyGraph");

        series.add(0, 1);
        series.add(1, 2);
        series.add(2, 5);
        series.add(7, 8);
        series.add(9, 10);

        XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
        dataset.addSeries(series);

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
                "XY Chart",
                "x-axis",
                "y-axis",
                dataset, 
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                true,
                true,
                false
                );
        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);

        //chart.getXYPlot().setRenderer(new XYSplineRenderer());

        panel.add(chartPanel);

        panel.setOpaque(true); 
        return panel;  
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("[=] There's a JPanel in here! [=]");

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        SplinePanel demo = new SplinePanel();
        frame.setContentPane(demo.createContentPane());

        // The other bits and pieces that make our program a bit more stable.
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1300, 650);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

The project is now available here:

https://github.com/bluesh34/SplinePanel/

Answer (score 0):

Using absolute paths to jars doesn't seem correct.
[image]

Proposal:

1. create a lib folder within your project
2. copy all the required jars to this lib folder
3. remove all wrong registered libs from project properties
4. re-add all the jars

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I already had a lib folder: I think I tried this method in the past already. Anyway, I copied the jars to lib and removed the jars from project properties. I went to project properties to re-add the jars but they had been added automatically (but the paths are still the same as the ones you said were wrong as they were absolute). Anyway, I'm afraid the errors are still there (including the one I put in the question).

Comment: Also I've no idea how, but I've forgotten where Resolve Project Problems is and can't find it. Could you tell me where it is please?